# Undefined Control Sequence error message

Tags: errors

I have just started using Latex, Here is the code I have used (Texstudio editor):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{''3B}
\newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
\begin{document}
\title{DSC4830\\[3mm]
    Research Project\\[5mm]
    Department of Decision Sciences\\[1cm]
    Assignment 1\\[5mm]
    Typing in \Latex\\[1cm]
}
\author{\textbf{\Large Lashner Ciorovich}\\[3mm]
    /textbf{\Large 07364598}
}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\np
\tableofcontents
\np
\end{document}
```

I keep getting the following logs:

> Missing number, treated as zero. \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{''3B}
>   Missing \begin{document}. \DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{''3B}
>   Undefined control sequence. \maketitle

Please can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Stop using `\np` and delete the definition from your file (else the monster under your bed might get upset). It seems you are usin the wrong document class. Your title is also a mess ([read more](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280)).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you typed `''` instead of `"` in the math symbol definition.

By the way there were other errors too, mainly:

1. The LaTeX logo is printed using `\LaTeX`, not `\Latex`
2. you had a `/textbf` instead of `\textbf`
3. finally, are you really sure about your substituting the comma and make it an `ord` math atom? **EDIT** should you want to use the comma as a decimal separator (as @GustavoMezzetti suggests), try and use the `siunitx` package, specifically loading it like `\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}`. I recommend you skim through [its documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) (you could obtain it also typing `texdoc siunitx` in your terminal window).

Anyway, here is my cleared up code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathord}{letters}{"3B}
\newcommand{\np}{\newpage}
\begin{document}
\title{DSC4830\\[3mm]
    Research Project\\[5mm]
    Department of Decision Sciences\\[1cm]
    Assignment 1\\[5mm]
    Typing in \LaTeX\\[1cm]
}
\author{\textbf{\Large Lashner Ciorovich}\\[3mm]
    \textbf{\Large 07364598}
}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\np
\tableofcontents
\np
\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

Comment: `\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{letters}{"3B}` does nothing but repeating the default definition: I guess that the OP really wishes to turn `,` into a `\mathord`.  You might kindly suggest to have a look to the `siunit`(`x`) package.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I use `siunitx` all the time, but why here? I corrected the `mathpunct` thing

Comment: I thought that the OP wanted to use `,` as a decimal separator, as in `$\pi = 3,1415926535897932384626433832795$` (if I recollect correctly the first digits of pi).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Well, perhaps so, I'll leave it as a suggestion on point 3, then, thanks